# onTouch ACTION_MOVE изменить слово

Tags: android

Нажимая на "А" и перетащить на квадрат "B" , что бы Получилось в TextView AB .... вот моя реализация но не работает :(

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements View.OnTouchListener {

Button btn, btn2;
TextView txw;
String dates;
int slide = 100;
float x;
float y;

@SuppressLint("ClickableViewAccessibility")
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);



    btn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn);
    btn2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn2);
    txw = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txw);

    btn.setOnTouchListener(this);
    btn2.setOnTouchListener(this);
    txw.setOnTouchListener(this);
}


@SuppressLint("SetTextI18n")
@Override
public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent motionEvent) {
    x = motionEvent.getX();
    y = motionEvent.getY();
    float ex = btn2.getX();
    float ey = btn2.getY();

    switch (motionEvent.getAction()) {
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN: // нажатие
             dates = (String) btn.getText();
            Log.e(TAG, "onTouch: DAtes = =" + dates );
            break;
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE: // движение
            if (x >= ex && x <= ex && y >= ey && y <= ey ){

                dates = dates+btn2.getText();
            }
            break;
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP: // отпускание

            break;

        case MotionEvent.ACTION_CANCEL:

            break;
    }
   txw.setText(dates);
    return true;
}
```

[image: OnTouch()]

Comment: x>=ex & & x<=ex даст true только если x=ex. Аналогично и со второй частью. Вам нужно поправить условия. Что вы хотели там написать?

Comment: Поправил теперь можете помочь?

Comment: @AndriyMartsinkevych Пожалуйста помогите

Comment: @talex помогите

Comment: У вас в вопросе так и осталось старое условие. Если самостоятельно не получится исправить то напишите мне на почту martsinkevych@gmail.com